# Java casting an exception (not class cast exception)

Tags: java, casting

When an exception is caught in java is there a use case for casting the exception to a new type? Or is the standard

```
    throw new DiffException(e)
```

The only way to do it. I apologize if I'm overlooking something but the only search results I get are for "ClassCastExceptions" Which is obviously not what I'm looking for

Comment: Why do you want to 'cast' the exception to a different exception type?  Can you give an example?

Comment: I didn't say I wanted to at all. The question itself is "are there and use cases for casting an exception" I've never seen it personally so I wanted to know if it has a legitimate use or if exception wrapping is it.

Comment: 'Casting the exception to a new type' doesn't mean anything. You can only cast an object to one of its super types or interfaces. Not to a new type. Your question remains unclear.

Comment: you can also downcast as well, if you know it is truely the derived exception.

Comment: @EJP obviously the question wasn't ambiguous to the 4+ people that answered and commented on it. And you vote to close it after I already accepted an answer? Go troll somewhere else Mr. Perfect. The point of asking this question was because I was unsure about it myself.

Comment: Yes, sometimes there are methods available to one type of exception and not another. the Saxon SAXParseException comes to mind--it has a method calld getSystemID() that exceptions wouldn't have otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you meant ['exception wrapping'](http://www.google.com/search?q=exception+wrapping). 
There's no other way to do it - you create a new instance of `Exception` using a constructor which takes another exception as cause. This works thanks to [1-arg constructor of java.lang.Exception](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html#Exception(java.lang.Throwable)). The typical implementation of custom exception type (like your `DiffException`) declares such 1-arg constructor too.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if the exception caught (`e` in your case I suppose) is a subtype of `DiffException`, you could of course *cast* it like

```
throw (DiffException) e;
```

but I doubt that's what you want to do, since it doesn't make a difference (the `e` will still have the same runtime type, even in the receiving end).

So the answer is most likely, **no**, there is no other, equivalent way, of doing

```
throw new DiffException(e);
```

than doing just that.

It should be noted however, that doing `new DiffException(e)` is not called *casting* but, *wrapping*, or *chaining* the exception.

Comment: Yeah sorry I was misusing the terminology

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly here is the use case I am thinking about.
expression:

```
new FileInputStream("the path");
```

may throw `FileNotFoundException` if the file does not exist. `FileNotFoundException` extends `IOException`, so you could write code like:

```
public void readFromFile(String path) {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(path);
    // do something....
}
```

Now you can call this method as following:

```
try {
    readFromFile("myFile");
} catch (IOException e) {
    if (e instanceof FileNotFoundException) {
        FileNotFoundException fnfe = (FileNotFoundException)e;
        // do something
    }
    // do something else
}
```

But I'd recommend you create separate catch blocks for `FileNotFoundException` and for `IOException` (at least for this use-case):

```
try {
    readFromFile("myFile");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // do something with FileNotFoundException
} catch (IOException e) {
    // do something with IOException
}
```

This code does not contain instanceof, casting and other ugly stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned use cases, the common one in Java is wrapping a checked exception as unchecked; this is appropriate when there's no way the checked exception can occur, such as here:

```
public static Reader getUTF8Reader(InputStream is) {
    try {
        return new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
    } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // should never happen since UTF-8 is guaranteed to be available as per
        // http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html
        throw new RuntimeException("UTF-8 not available", e);
    }
}
```

Without wrapping the exception, you'd either have to swallow it (which feels wrong) or declare the method as `throws UnsupportedEncodingException` which forces anyone using it to catch *the exception that will never be thrown*. Wrapping it, there's no onus on the caller to handle unlikely cases, yet we're protected in the unlikely event that UTF-8 isn't available on some obscure platform in the future.