# Problems handling Exceptions

Tags: java, exception

I've created my own exception but when I try to use it I receive a message saying that it can't be cast to my exception

I've got one interface like this

```
public interface MyInterface
{   
    public OtherClass generate(ClassTwo two, ClassThree three) throws RetryException;
}
```

other like this one

```
public class MyGenerator{   
  public class generate (ClassTwo two, ClassThree three){
    try{
    }catch(MyException my)
  }
}
```

and finally a method in another class

```
public Object evaluate(String expression, Map values) throws FirstException, RetryException
{
   try{
   }catch (Exception x){
     if(x instanceof FirstException){
       throw new FirstException()
     }
     else{
       RetryException retry= (RetryException)x;
       retry.expression = expression;
       retry.position = position;
       retry.operator = tokens[position];
       retry.operand = 1;
       throw retry; 
     }
  }
}
```

This try catch block on the last method is to make maths operation and I want to catch a division by zero exception on the `RetryException`.

Comment: I fixed the code tags, then someone edited behind me and messed them up....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174869/java-casting-an-exception-not-class-cast-exception

Comment: Just a comment: don't use `if(x instanceof FirstException)` in catch blocks, use multiple catch blocks instead.

Comment: Show the actual code and stacktrace of the exception.  You don't have any code to actually generate an exception shown.

Comment: how is `RetryException` defined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
RetryException retry= (RetryException)x;
```

This line of code is attempting to cast an Exception as a RetryException. This will only work if: RetryException appropriately extends the Exception type that you are catching (ArithmeticException for divide by zero, I think?). AND the Exception actually IS a RetryException. Without looking at more of your logic, we have no idea if this is true.

Try checking

```
if (x instanceof RetryException)
```

Before you do this cast. Your code may be throwing a different kind of Exception.

Preferably, you would instead have multiple catch blocks...

```
try{
//}catch (FirstException e) -- I removed this, as you are only catching it and then directly
                        //     throwing it, which seems uneecessary
}catch (RetryException r){
    //process r
    throw r;
}
```

If I misunderstood your question, I'll do my best to correct this.

Comment: Sam DeHaan in my code the exception follow this tree `Exception -> MyFirstException -> RetryException`

Comment: so, nobody have a solution for me?

Comment: What it comes down to is this: You are trying to cast an Exception to a RetryException (`(RetryException)x`). The exception is not necessarily a RetryException, so this is failing. We offered a few solutions to this, but you have not accepted them or provided reasons why they will not work.

Comment: so, i see the only solution is to extend it to ArithmeticException instead

Answer (score 4):

I am going to make some big assumptions here as to what is happening, since the code examples are very incomplete.

In your evaluate method, you are getting an ArithmeticException due to a divide by zero and you want to handle it by throwing your own RetryException in the handler.  The exception received cannot be casted since it is of the wrong type, you should catch the ArithmeticException in your evaluate method and then create and throw a new RetryException.

```
public Object evaluate(String expression, Map values) throws FirstException, RetryException
{
   try{
       // Some code that may throw FirstException
       int x = 10/0;
   }catch (ArithmeticException x){  // Handle divide by zero
       RetryException retry= new RetryException();
       retry.setExpression(expression);
       retry.setPosition(position);
       retry.setOperator(tokens[position]);
       retry.setOperand(1);
       throw retry; 
     }
  }
}
```

This all assumes that an appropriate RetryException exists with the appropriate setter methods of course.

FirstException catch was removed since it was hiding the real stacktrace by creating a new instance when none is required.  It is already declared in the method signature and there was no actual handling.

Comment: A good answer, but pretty malformed Java code. `setProperty() = x` should be `setProperty(x)`

Comment: @Sam DeHaan Yes it is, I was just refactoring the OP's code and was being a little hasty.  Thanks for pointing it out, it is now fixed.

Comment: Yes, refactoring is great, just didn't want to +1 until it was corrected.

Comment: The problem is that this `Exception` is suppose  to handle any type of `Exception` for example when it finds a letter instead of a number